# Dell XPS 15 (9560) wifi not working

Tags: wireless, 17.10, xps

So I recently got a dell xps 15 with the idea of using it as a linux machine. I assumed it would work pretty smoothly given the xps's reputation with linux, but I'm having quite the amount of trouble getting the wifi working.

So when I first tried Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 the wifi actually worked, sort of at least. I could connect to my the guest network at my university, but not the secure network. Then, the wifi just stopped working all together a day later.

The confusing thing to me is that there seems to be a lot of other people who got Ubuntu working straight out of the gate. [This person](https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)) didn't seem to have any issues with the wifi. I tried updating the bios because I saw somewhere that that might help, but that didn't seem to do anything.

The chip is a Qualcomm Atheros Killer 1535 802.11ac to be specific. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I should clarify, the wifi networks show up. So the card is being used in someway. But I can't connect to any network.

Comment: Show us `sudo lshw -C network`. You should inspect the logs to see if, among the thousands of lines, there is something about your WiFi. `journalctl -b` will show you all logs since boot.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with something like this years ago with a different laptop, had to find the correct driver than manually install it, quick search found this-

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322168

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that when I get a chance. After doing a bit more research, its seems like the stock wifi cards have been kind of flaky... So it could be a problem with the card itself, that would explain why only some xps users seem to have the issue.

Comment: From what I have found certain flavors will work with certain hardware better, for example I have seen ubuntu work right after install on a certain model laptop where something like kali requires manually configuring some of the hardware.

Comment: Ok so I may have gotten things somewhat working. I figured out the reason I couldn't connect to the secure wifi was because I wasn't leaving the anonymous field blank. As for the wifi cutting in and out, I switched to 17.10 and that seems to have maybe fixed it? It's hard to tell because it's so sporadic. I also updated the linux firmware http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/. I'll give it a couple days and see if it goes ballistic again like it did in 16.04.